# How to update scss on host

Tags: sass, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made a wordpress theme with understrap and I have uploaded on a webhost and it works fine.
The issue is that I wanted to make some changes so I edit my scss file localy and when I uploaded it the changes weren't applied. Am I suppose to upload any other file in order to work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone but in order to update website's scss on host you simply copy the css file which usually is in the css folder and you just upload it to the same folder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30129433)

Answer (score 0):

The SCSS needs to be compiled into - and replace the existing - CSS files enqueued by your theme. To do this you can either, install a plugin that does that, or have it done by setting up css pre-processing in your local IDE/environment.

Answer (score 0):

clear cache of your browser and close recent tab and try again. it just browser runnung with previous cache.

Comment: Your answer has spelling errors and an incomplete sentence whose meaning is unclear. Please, do not be "fast and furious" when write your answers: Take time to reread them, spot the mistakes and fix them, and do your best to be clear and understandable when detailing the steps to solve the problem.